# Linq query on ISet collection

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have a Customer with a list of Contacts. This list is an ISet collection. I can't do a Linq query on it. Could you help me for this ?

Thanks,

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

Customer customer = session.Get(id);
customer.Contacts = // Error - customer.Contacts.Where(x => x.Id != contactId);
```

Update 1

Tried this : `from p in customer.Contacts.AsEnumerable() where p.Id != id select p;`
*error on the where.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' 
to 'Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet'.
 An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Answer (score 4):

I believe this problem has nothing to do with IESI ISet<T> implementing IEnumerable<T> (it *does*, BTW), but the answer is instead pointed to by the cast exception mentioned in the 'update' to the original post.

The line...

```
customer.Contacts = customer.Contacts.Where(x => x.Id != contactId);
```

...does in fact (incorrectly) attempt to assign an IEnumerable<Contact> (the result of the .Where(...) operator) to a property of type ISet<Contact> (the .Contacts property on the Customer class).

I strongly suspect that this line would be fine...

```
IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = customer.Contacts.Where(x => x.Id != contactId);
```

...demonstrating that the .Where(...) operator works just fine on the IESI ISet<T> but that what .Where(...) returns is (of course) IEnumerable<T>.

For this to work, you need to convert the result of your .Where(...) operation from IEnumerable<T> to ISet<T> before attempting to assign it to the customer.Contacts property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming ISet is `System.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>`.

Add a using statement for `System.Linq`, and possibly a reference to `System.Core.dll`.

---

If it's something else as the root namespace `Iesi` might indicate, can you use the standard `ISet<T>`? Or, can you somehow convert your `ISet<T>` to an `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: No it's the ISet collection from NHibernate